# How did "grifo" become the Spanish for "faucet"?

Tags: etimología

While studying the etymology of the word, I found that it comes from ***gryphus***, the Latin for *griffin*. In fact *griffin* also happens to be one meaning of **grifo**. And as we all know, *griffin* is a mythical beast with the body of a lion and the head of an eagle. *Griffin* is also the name of a species of vultures.

What I don't understand then is how **grifo** became the Spanish for a water faucet. It seems random but I am sure there's some logic behind it. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Nice question. A note: griffins have upper half of an eagle (with claws, not paws) and lower half of a lion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most probable cause is that drains in antique buildings, especially churches had different forms of fantastic animals, people or normal animals, and here is where griffins appears. In Italian there is *rubinetto* and French has *robinet*. Both with faucet meaning because of the same origin, fonts had sheep sculptures.

You can see this site:

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?grifo

Comment: Great answer. I was **just** about to share the same reference when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The term grifo is relatively new regarding faucets. It looks like it started to be called like this when faucet makers started to build them representing a griffin, in the 18th century.

Comment: You can turn a good answer into a **great** one by sharing your references. That way other users would know that you are not just saying it, but that there's evidence of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. unfortunately I can't remember where did I learn this as this was long time ago. that's why I put "It looks like" as I can't name my sources

Comment: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?grifo en su segundo apartado lo menciona: " En España, antiguamente no se usaba la palabra **grifo** para referirse a la llave del agua. Antes del siglo XVIII, se usaba la palabra **canilla** (del latín _canícula_, o pequeña caña) para referirse a la boca de la cañería donde sale el agua y todavía se usa en ese sentido en Argentina. La palabra **grifo** substituyó la palabra **canilla**, por el cambio de tecnología, cuando la boca de la fuente de agua se empezó a construir en forma de esta ave."

Comment: El "Manual pràctico de agricultura y economía rural: escrito por un labrador ..." (1822) https://books.google.es/books?id=Q4S74E_Pqt0C&pg=PA90&dq=%22grifo%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8o4LCmN3PAhXkAsAKHWz8BKEQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=%22grifo%22&f=false recoge: "...introduciéndolo como si fuera un grifo o canilla ...."